# Highstock navigator afterSetExtremes() timeout

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple Highstock.js line chart with a minimalistic navigator. This navigator contains just 2 points within a timespan of one year, to give the user the possibility to scroll back. The default interval should be one hour. When scrolling back, series data should be retrieved via ajax requests. That works fine.

My Problem is, that when I click on a specific date on the navigator (with default zoom, right after the chart has been initialized) the afterSetExtremes() events is fired with an enormous timeout.

```
function afterSetExtremes(e) {
$('#debug').html(e.min + "-" + e.max);  
}
```

I have configured a simple example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hN56D/3/

Thanks for your help. BR.

Comment: Try to disable `ordinal` option for xAxis, see: http://jsfiddle.net/hN56D/4/

Comment: Great hint! Seems it works now. Thanks a lot Pawel!